# About Swtich Statments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I write this code to try my idea and is working fine :

```js
var answer = prompt("Please type your gender? male / female");
var gender = answer;
switch (gender) {
  case "female":
    console.log("Hello, madame!");
    break;
  case "male":
    console.log("Hello, sir!");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Hello!");
}
```

But the problem for example when someone add answer with uppercase like "**MALE**" or Capital Letter like "**Male**" so this code is not working. any idea about that to get working in any statments of words ( Lowercase / Uppercase / Capital Letter )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the input to lower case:

```
switch (gender.toLowerCase()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var gender = answer.toLowerCase();
```

Also, please indent your code in future.